# SQL Condition spanning multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on an ordering system based on a PostgreSQL database, so that I have a `OrderLines` table of the following form:

```
order_id     int
product_id   int
quantity     int
```

Each order is then composed of one row in this table per unique product ordered.

I'm trying to run queries of the form:

- *For each order containing products A, B and C, give me the quantities for products C and D*
- *For each order containing products A and (B or C), give me the quantities for product D*
- *For each order containing products A and at least 2 * B, give me the quantities for A, B and C*

The condition here can potentially have deeply nested clauses.
There can be millions of orders, and 10k+ lines per order.
The conditions cannot be known in advance. Should a product not be in an order, its quantity should be returned as 0.

Do you have any directions regarding writing queries with conditions that span multiple rows, such as this one?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: This is done. PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think if you aggregated the quantities of each part for all orders in a CTE, like this:

```
with summary as (
  select
    order_id,
    sum (case when product_id = 'A' then quantity else 0 end) as a,
    sum (case when product_id = 'B' then quantity else 0 end) as b,
    sum (case when product_id = 'C' then quantity else 0 end) as c,
    sum (case when product_id = 'D' then quantity else 0 end) as d
  from table
  where quantity != 0
  group by order_id
)
```

(Side note -- you said product_id is an integer but listed values that are text -- I assume there is a reasonable explanation, but I did not attempt to reconcile this)

You could use that as the basis to answer each of the three questions:

For each order containing products A, B and C, give me the quantities for products C and D

```
select order_id, c, d
from summary
where a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0
```

For each order containing products A and (B or C), give me the quantities for product D

```
select order_id, d
from summary
where a > 0 and (b > 0 or c > 0)
```

For each order containing products A and at least 2 * B, give me the quantities for A, B and C

```
select order_id, a, b, c
from summary
where a > 0 and (a + b + c + d > 2 * b)
```

I would also wrap "summary" in a materialized view if you are going to run lots of scenarios like this, especially with the data volumes you are talking about.

If the example is notional and there are actually hundreds of item numbers or more, then I would skip the CTE/view and build each case with the relevant scenarious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  For instance for the first:

> For each order containing products A, B and C, give me the quantities for products C and D

```
select order_id,
       sum(quantity) filter (where product_id = C) as c_quantity,
       sum(quantity) filter (where product_id = D) as d_quantity
from orderlines ol
group by order_id
having count(*) filter (where product_id = A) > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where product_id = B) > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where product_id = C) > 0 ;
```

The other questions can be handled with similar logic, changing the `having` conditions or the `sum()`s.